# How to display with php only area postal-code and region?

Tags: php, location, postal-code

I need a little help. I'd like to show visitors their "region_name" and "zip_code"

I found the following source code, but don't know how to modify it and have the result show only region and zip code.

```
<?php // work
  $location = file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.net/json/'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
  print_r($location);
?>
```

Please All, can you help me, if it is possible? I have tried:

```
echo $zipcode = $location['zip_code'];
```

but this does not work.

Comment: Why `echo $zipcode = $location['zip_code'];` does nothing ? Because `$zipcode = $location['zip_code'];` is an assignation and returns nothing. So your instruction evaluate as follow: `echo $zipcode = $location['zip_code'];` -> `echo null;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$location =file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.net/json/'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$location = json_decode($location);

echo $location->zip_code;
```

Comment: make it a good answer, and do tell why this would work vis OPs code. Also a link to the json_decode php manual would be good!